# How to compute conditional distribution conditioned on a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

As mentioned in the subject. My question is to simply compute the density function which is conditioned on another continuous random variable. The only thing to specify is that both random variables are normally distributed ($\mathcal{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_{\mathcal{X}}^2) , \mathcal{Y}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_{\mathcal{Y}}, \sigma_{\mathcal{Y}}^2)$). Then what would be $f_{\mathcal{X}|\mathcal{Y}}$.

To make it more clear, how to compute further variables like $\mu_{\mathcal{X}|\mathcal{Y}}$ and $\sigma_{\mathcal{X}|\mathcal{Y}}^2$

Comment: You need joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ to answer this unless of course $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Is there any analytical expression for that. For discrete variables I can compute. But I am having difficulties in actually implementing them in computer when it comes to continuous variables. Can you please suggest a good source